# Как вести логгирование JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как хорошо вести логгирование `JavaScript` программы?
Ну, естественно на серверной части.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть библиотечка [log4javascript](http://log4javascript.org/), которая через [AjaxAppender](http://log4javascript.org/docs/manual.html#ajaxappender) шлет логи на сервер.

В сети рекомендуют использовать [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/ajax-onerror/) для интересующих событий, например, ошибок:

```
window.onerror = function (msg, url, line) {
    if (encodeURIComponent) {
        var req = new AjaxRequest();
        var params = "msg=" + encodeURIComponent(msg) + '&amp;url=' + encodeURIComponent(url) + "&amp;line=" + line;
        req.setMethod("POST");
        return req.loadXMLDoc("<i>/scripts/logerror.php</i>", params);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Думаю, можно также подцепить [Google Analytics](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingCustomVariables.html) на пользовательские переменные, и добавлять их всюду, куда только нужно.

Comment: Замечательная вещь!!!
Спасибо!